# Using GROUP BY statement but still showing duplicates

Tags: mysql

was trying to call out each type of item from table once, i already putting in group by statement in my sql query but it still echoes out duplicate data.

Here's the code and database sample

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","test");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM testing GROUP BY Name";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

[image: database]

Comment: just do `select name from testing group by name` or `select distinct name from testing`

Comment: @GurV did what u ask but the result is the same... all 4 item shown instead of 3

Comment: Post the code in the question which you used and the output you got

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is the problem with your current result? Can you provide example data, expected result, clear problem definition? Can you tell us the structure of the table? According to the rules used by MySQL to handle GROUP BY clauses the result may or may not predictable for your query.

Comment: @Pred was hoping to get each item to be call out once instead of everything in the table but the result i keep getting is the everything from that table was echo out

Comment: `SELECT name, LENGTH(name), BIT_LENGTH(name) FROM testing WHERE name LIKE '%apple%'` <- What is the result of this query?

Comment: @Pred getting 3 output instead of everything but duplicates still remains

Comment: I meant, what are the lengths? Are they the same? If they are different, that means, you have spaces or other characters stored in some of the records. You can try to trim the data (remove whitespaces from the beginning and end of the string). Whitespace counts in comparison and GROUP  BY is a kind of comparison.

Comment: @RaymondChok How do you say there are duplicate records? I can see that still fields `ID` and `Record_ID` have distinct value. If you do not need those `ID` and `Record_ID` fields, remove it from `SELECT` and add `distinct` keyword in `SELECT` statement.

Comment: @Pred already checked that there is no spaces in between the string

Comment: If you do this `SELECT Name FROM testing GROUP BY Name` and there are still 'duplicates' it means there is a difference somewhere. Spec character, whitespace, whatever, but there is something.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you can try..

```
<?php
     $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","test");
     $sql = "SELECT distinct name, Record_ID, Shop_ID  FROM testing";
     $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
         echo $row['name'];
            echo "<br>";

     }
?>
```

Comment: Why, how this helps, any kind of explanation? Please note that the DISTINCT keyword affects the processing of RECORDS, not individual columns!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:-

```
 Select distinct name from testing;
```